# Determine if the Set is open or closed.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

$A:=\lbrace x\in \mathbb{R}^4: ||x-(0,1,0,1)^T||_2<2\rbrace$

I am assuming that it is closed, because $A^c$ is $||x-(0,1,0,1)^T||_2\geq2$ is open, but how to can I prove that?

Comment: $A^c$ is **not** open. In fact, $A$ is an *open ball* around $(0,1,0,1)$.

Comment: Strict inequalities $<$ or $>$ are often a tip off that your starting hypothesis should be the set is open.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi you are right, I meant the opposite that $A^c$ is closed.

Comment: How do you know $A^c$ is closed?  If you really *do* know that then you *have* just proven A is open.

Comment: You had a theorem early on that all open balls are open.  An open ball $B(q, r)$ are all the points x such that d(q, x) < r.  I'm assuming $|| ... ||_2$ is the norm, and $(0,1,01)^T$ is a point.  Then $B((0,1,01)^T, 2) = A$ and there isn't anything left to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that $A$ is an open ball. You can't get much more direct than that!